# How do I set a default naming convention for subscriptions and queues in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

Currently we are tied to a single Azure Service Bus instance for local and the test environment (I would prefer a different setup but It's not up to me). Previously we were using a custom framework that for each topic it created a subscrption with a name that was a mix of the service name and, if the project was run by a dev in his machine, it appended a "local name" to avoid having all the dev local computers and the server instances competing for the same message. So for example for the ShoppingService it created a subscription called ShoppingService for the server instances and in Joe's local machine it created a subscription called let's say ShoppingService-JoeComputer. Right now we are trying to switch from this custom framework to MassTransit because we like the additional features it provides (and also because honestly the custom framework was more buggy than we would like to admit). We followed this video published by Patterson to create the commands, events and consumers and everything works as described:

[MassTransit - Using Azure Service Bus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BbazfX_Tf4)

However, we are now facing the competition issue I mentioned before. To solve it we will try to set the custom naming convention we are currently using so the questions I have are:

1. Is there a way to modify the default naming convention used by MassTransit? We would like to keep most of it where it creates a topic based on the command type name but we would like to add a postfix to both the forwarding subscription and the queue. In other words if we were talking about the submit order command described in the video we would like the subscription name to be "submit-order-joe" and the queue name to be "submit-order-joe" if it runs on joe's machine. We could set up the configuration manually for each consumer/client/publisher but it would be great if we can set it up "globally".
2. Using the default convention, what happens if there are two commands named "namespaceOne.SubmitOrder" and "namespaceTwo.SubmitOrder"? Based on what we saw it would create two different topics but both subscriptions would be called "submit-order" and both would forward messages to the same queue called "submit-order". That would be confusing and I don't even know if MassTransit is going to consume the commands correctly.

Comment: Hi, can you post the code for us to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two naming conventions in MassTransit. Entity names (which are based upon message type, and would be topics in Azure Service Bus) and endpoint names (which are based upon the consumer, saga, or activity type and would be queues in ASB).

You can specify your own [entity name formatter](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/message.html) to customize the entity name format, or you can override specific messages.

You can also specify your own [endpoint name formatter, described in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsUlQ93j2MY) to customize the queue names generated for receive endpoints. Or you can create an instance of the built-in formatters specifying different constructor arguments to include a prefix, include the namespace, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chris-pattherson, that is exactly what I'm looking for. I only have one question regarding the subscription created when using request/response pattern. The queue has the expected name, but the subscription has some weird characters at the end:

[Image here](https://imgur.com/a/Vwa6Z2d)

Comment: If the name exceeds the character limit, it will truncate it and append a hashed value to keep it unique.